# Installation of Indivo Database - Errors during Testing Indivo Backend Server

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am a Computer Engineering UG student, working on a research project on Explanation of Health Data. For my project, I am required to access the Indivo health database. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 in Oracle's VirtualBox, with my host laptop OS in Windows 8.1.

I completed all steps of installation as per the instructions here - http://docs.indivohealth.org/en/2.0/howtos/install-ubuntu.html. Out of the three options, I have installed MySQL for database.

But I am stuck while **Testing backend server**. I am always receiving two errors -

osboxes@osboxes:~/IndivoHDB/indivo_server$ python manage.py cleanup_old_tokens

osboxes@osboxes:~/IndivoHDB/indivo_server$ python manage.py test indivo

Creating test database for alias 'default'...

## .................F............................................................................................

## RUNNING INTEGRATION TESTS:

=============================================================================
Report:
.......... pass : Document Handling Test

.......... pass : Sharing

.......... pass : PHA Document Handling

.......... pass : PHAing record_app delete

.......... pass : PHAing app delete

.......... pass : AppSpecific

.......... pass : Document Metadata Test

.......... pass : OAuthing

.......... pass : Binary Document Test

.......... pass : Accounting

.......... pass : Record Shares

.......... pass : Messaging

.......... pass : Special Document Handling

.......... pass : Auditing

.......... pass : Document Processing Test

.......... pass : Security

=============================================================================

## ......................................................................................................................E.........................................

### ERROR: test_get_smart_ontology (indivo.tests.api.smart_tests.SMARTInternalTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/osboxes/IndivoHDB/indivo_server/indivo/tests/api/smart_tests.py", line 11, in test_get_smart_ontology
    response = self.client.get('/ontology')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 439, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 241, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/osboxes/IndivoHDB/indivo_server/indivo/lib/utils.py", line 38, in **call**
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osboxes/IndivoHDB/indivo_server/indivo/views/smart_container.py", line 19, in smart_ontology
    ontology = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1199, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1169, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError:

======================================================================

### FAIL: test_get_connect_credentials (indivo.tests.api.accounts_tests.AccountInternalTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/osboxes/IndivoHDB/indivo_server/indivo/tests/api/accounts_tests.py", line 376, in test_get_connect_credentials
    self.assertEqual(db_rt.expires_at, iso8601.parse_utc_date(data.findtext('ExpiresAt')))
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 5, 36, 32) != datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 5, 36, 32, 977919)

---

Ran 270 tests in 301.989s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Please help me, as I am totally naive at this.

Answer (score 0):

For my setup also I have seen the same error and I have contacted their google group and found that we can silently ignore that error and go ahead and see the things actually works or not. Mine is working fine eventhough i came across that errors.